# Using wget and wput for only newest files

Tags: bash, ftp, wget

**For background,** I've files I need to transport between servers, and to do this I've had a stab at writing a bash script which uses wget to retrieve only the newest files and wput to upload them.

**The problem** is that I'm using wget with the -N flag and whilst this downloads the most recent file, it also means that when I come to use wput I'm then uploading all files and not just the newest. Where it gets trickier is that I have to upload to a specific directory and, once uploaded, they are moved to a different one so I can't use what I've uploaded in the past as a guide.

**What I'd like** is to only upload the newest files that have been downloaded and if nothing has been downloaded then for the script to exit.

Any help on how I could achieve this would be greatly appreciated, my current code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Redirect stdout ( > ) into a named pipe ( >() ) running "tee"
exec > >(tee -i update_logfile.txt)
exec 2>&1

today="$(date +'%d%m%Y')"

printf "Record load started: %s\n" "$today"

echo "get records" 
wget -N ftp://[user1]:[pass1]@[ftp-server-1]/*.* -P /path/to/temp/

echo "put records" 
wput --basename=/path/to/temp/ -u  /path/to/temp/*.*  ftp://[user2]:[pass2]@[ftp-server-2]/update/

echo "upload finished" 

mail -s "Upload" my_email@domain.com < update_logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Joesch- Simple approach would be to write a lastCheck with a timestamp of last download to a file file and check the timestamp against last modified of files to be uploaded. if teh file is newer then the timestamp, upload it. It should be fairly simple to do, but feel free to let me know and i can put snippet together for you.

Comment: Hi Amol, I'm not sure I follow. Would you mind giving me an example? I'm not very experienced with shell scripting.

Comment: Joesch- I’m in travel and on cellphone. I won’t be able to give code snippet (though I would love to :)  ). I would follow these steps-  1. When file is downloaded, write a temp file with time stamp. 2. When the uploading the file, look at the file name and the time stamp to see if this is the file that was modified. This way you avoid duplication of files that were uploaded. My apologies for answer format but I hope this helps.